# Why ant design doesn't provided CSS documentation like bootstrap?

Tags: css, antd, ant-design-pro, ng-zorro-antd

Is there is any ant design CSS documentation like bootstrap available?
We are using ng-zorro-antd framework to build Angular application.

ng-zorro-antd provide grid compnents:

```
<div nz-row>
      <div nz-col nzSpan="6">col-6</div>
      <div nz-col nzSpan="6">col-6</div>
</div>
```

But its not feasible to use angular component at every html design/structure we want something like the below class.

```
<div class="ant-row">
  <div class="ant-col-6">col-6</div>
  <div class="ant-col-6">col-6</div>     
</div>
```

Also Need to know about performance of CSS based grid Vs component or directive based structure.
Is there is any performance impact?

Comment: did you checked https://ant.design/components/button/ ?

Comment: yes checked but these are all components.
we want something like bootstrap classes.So that we can use these CSS classes to design custom layout .